# Return array from a function in cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cypress

`getLinksByElementAttribute = async (element, attribute) => { /**@type{array}*/ let arrayHTML = [];` 
`return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {`

```
        cy.get(element).each(($el, index) => {
            
            //cy.log();
            
            arrayHTML[index] = $el.attr(attribute);

            resolve(arrayHTML);   
           
           
        });

    cy.log(arrayHTML)
    });

}
```

}

I am passing 'a' tag as element and 'href' as attribute and would like to have all the links on webpage which I got using arrayHTML[index] stored in an array together, any help on how to store the links together and return them as one array ?

When I currently run the code then I see the cy.log return value 'Array[52]' in log file for my weblink,means I have 52 'a' elements on my web page,  any idea on how I can see actual values of 52 found elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because of the asynchronous behavior of cypress. One solution could be to use *cy.wrap()* and *JSON.stringify()*:

```
cy.wrap(arrayHTML)
  .then((array) => cy.log(JSON.stringify(array)));
```

More information here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Mixing-Async-and-Sync-code

Comment: This works fine, any way to return this array to xyz.spec.js file? , I am using this code in Page Object file which is in support folder, thanks